# Which layout is used for Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, layout, galaxy-nexus

Which Layout Can I used for Nexus 4 and Galaxy Nexus?

There is conflict between Nexus 7(800 x 1280) and Galaxy Nexus(720 x 1280) as attached in 
screenshot :

**Nexus S**

[image: Nexus S]

**Galaxy Nexus**

[image: Galaxy Nexus]

**EDIT**

**home_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <include layout="@layout/home_tab_list" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_bar_background" >
        </TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**home_tab_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/glob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture_description"
        android:src="@drawable/globe" />

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/createTrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pickMatches"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/glob"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture_description"
        android:src="@drawable/create_trip_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pickMatches"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/glob"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80.5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture_description"
        android:src="@drawable/pick_matches_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/meetMatch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/createTrip"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture_description"
        android:src="@drawable/meet_match_background" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please guide me on this.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In order to help you show a snippet of the code you use.

Comment: Nexus 7 is 1280*1920...

Comment: @DiegoPalomar : Ok,Added code.Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

**TabHost is deprecated** and it is recommended you use **[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)** instead.

Try out [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

> ActionBarSherlock is an extension of the support library designed to facilitate the use of the action bar design pattern across all versions of Android with a single API.
>
> The library will automatically use the native action bar when appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.

Tutorials:

[tutorial 1](http://avilyne.com/?p=180) , [tutorial 2](http://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/using-an-actionbar-in-your-application-with-actionbarsherlock/) ,
[tutorial 3](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/)

If you really want to use TabHost, maybe someone else can help. I don't have much experience with that. Good luck!

Comment: I forgot to mention that Google has its own alternative to ActionBarSherlock. **ActionBarCompat** http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: I have not issue with tabhost.I have problem with layout to which I want to use with Galaxy Nexus?