# How to create seperate layout for Galaxy Nexus and 5.1"WVGA,Nexus S(Android)

Tags: android, layout, galaxy-nexus

After trying a lot and finding a lot,Finally I want to ask a question that,

How to create layout for for **Galaxy Nexus and 5.1"WVGA,Nexus S**.They all come under the category of `Layout(Normal layout).` When I set layout for **5.1" WVGA then it will distorted in Galaxy Nexus** and when I create layout for **Galaxy Nexus then it will distorted in 5.1" WVGA.** So how can I create or organize for two different view.

Please guide me on this.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may wish to explain, **completely and precisely**, what "distorted" means. Feel free to upload screenshots (if you cannot do that directly here, upload them somewhere else and link to them here).

Comment: you should not be creating layouts specifically for devices, your layouts should be device independent. see http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Comment: @CommonsWare : distorted means it is not arranged properly.You can see screenshot here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850037/which-layout-is-used-for-galaxy-nexus